# I am getting error during "yarn start" command

Tags: node.js, redux, redux-thunk, yarnpkg

> E:\GIT\xxxx-ui\node_modules\redux-thunk\index.d.ts
>   (14,84): error TS2315: Type 'Middleware' is not generic.